# if i put the code in my theme's function.php file can it work?

Tags: filters, templates

```
$gr_preview_theme = $_GET['preview_theme'];
$gr_preview_css = $_GET['preview_css'];

if (! $gr_preview_css ) 
    $gr_preview_css = $gr_preview_theme;

if($gr_preview_theme && file_exists(get_theme_root() . "/$gr_preview_theme")) {
    add_filter('template','use_preview_theme');
}

if($gr_preview_css && file_exists(get_theme_root() . "/$gr_preview_css")) {
    add_filter('stylesheet','use_preview_css');
}


function use_preview_theme($themename) {
    global $gr_preview_theme;

    return $gr_preview_theme;
}

function use_preview_css($cssname) {
    global $gr_preview_css;

    return $gr_preview_css;
}
```

a pludgin's code is too small. i want to put the code into the theme's function.php file. could i do this?

```
add_filter('template','use_preview_theme');
```

what's the above line meaning? and what's use of it? thank you

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: i tried, it can. if i put it into the function.ph.are there some performance to affect wordpress? add_filter('template','use_preview_theme');what's the above line meaning? and what's use of it? thank you

Comment: post a link to the plugin

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-preview/

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer YES!! why because all a functions files does is act as a big huge plugin. Keep in mind though if you plan on using this with other themes or if in network mode you need the plugin file

Comment: add_filter('template','use_preview_theme');
what's the above line meaning? and what's use of it? thank you

Comment: its a filter to intercept a function and add the function indicated after , so I could put a new function name it whatever and then add a filter with that. look at your functions.pup folder for more info also check out teentytens function file for a better understanding